# Blender .fbx -> Spark AR Studio scaling issue for skeleton animations

Tags: blender, fbx, spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to create a character with skeleton animation in Blender to bring into Spark AR Studio. In Spark I want to use the baked animation. The .fbx brings the model and skeleton into Spark's scene just fine, until a new animation controller is selected via the object's inspector window and the animation is selected for use.

At that point, the Empty object named "Armature" is scaled to 100 instead of 1 and cannot be changed.

As a workaround, the Skeleton child object named "skeleton" can be scaled to 0.01. In Blender, I tried changing the scene's units and made sure the object's scales were all applied. Nothing is scaled to 100, everything is scaled to 1.

Since the object from the .fbx imports into Spark with correct scaling, I expect the animation to maintain that, but once the animation is selected the scale jumps from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Put you animated object inside some nullObject and then scale down not animated but nullObject. Hope it is clear.